# Aptana 3 - Global Resource Filters?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

Is there a way to have a global resource filter? For instance, to exclude backup files from the project view, such as '~' or 'bak', I have to set the resource filters on a per-project basis.

It would really be super nice if I could tell Aptana to filter certain files across all projects.